# soalris swap space issue when starting the java process

Tags: weblogic, solaris, swap, space

I have an issue with my Swap space on solaris sparc 10 os. When I start the Weblogic Server 10.3.3, the swap space utilization increases to 1.6 GB( Initially the swap space utilization is 200mb or 300MB )

Configuration Details:
OS : Solaris Sparc 10
JDK: Jrockit R27 version
RAM: 18 GB
Swap Space: 2GB

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you measuring swap usage ?

Answer (score 0):

A 2 GB swap looks too small for your 18 GB RAM system. You might simply need to add some swap space. Either a whole slice, partition, zvol or plain file, depending on your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.SO,What's the general rule of thumb on deciding about the swap size in solaris with respect to the RAM.

Comment: Any rule of thumb might trigger a flame war. The real rule is to have a swap large enough for all your memory allocation and reservation to fit. Too large a swap doesn't have any performance impact. Too small will have a critical impact on functionality.

Comment: @Nikhil, having a large swap has absolutely no negative effect on performance. What is bad for performance is not an oversized swap, it is an undersized RAM. In any case, there is probably no swapping issue here but just a virtual memory reservation confusion.

Answer (score 0):

2GB of swap on a 18GB RAM host is too low. There is no way to define a "math function" to set the swap space, but, a common rule may be a 2/3*Total RAM when you have more than 8GB and 2*RAM in other case.

But the amount of swap depends on the type of applications, and how they use the swap, so, you need to know it before assign a value. Otherwise if you have "a lot of free space" you can explore with diferent values a good start point may be 4GB.

You can add a raw device using:

```
# swap -a /dev/rdsk/cXtYdZsX
```

Or you can add a flat file

```
# mkfile -s 2048m /var/swap.file1
# swap -a /var/swap.file1
```

Here you have a complete example (in spanish) [Add more swap to a Solaris Host](http://sparcki.blogspot.com/2009/09/como-ampliar-la-swap-en-solaris.html)

Also, you can check the *tmpfs* (/tmp and /var/tmp) to avoid use entire free RAM, [Limit /tmp size on Solaris](http://sparcki.blogspot.com/2010/10/como-limitar-el-tamano-de-tmp-en.html)

Thanks,
Urko

Comment: Your swap -a command is incorrect, you should specify a slice or a partition. Moreover, you shouldn't write "you need at least xxx". Swap size requirement depends on applications memory usage, it is not proportional to the installed RAM size so there can be no rule based on it.

Comment: Hi jiliagre, Yes your're right i missed the slice (i've updatted) also, it's true there is no "math function" to set the swap but, there is a "good start point" (on SunSolve now Metalink) about the minimum swap space. Thanks in advance